# django 1.8 SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE not working

Tags: python, django, session

Django 1.7 had a problem with SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = true in Chrome, not expiring when the browser closes. I moved to Django 1.8, I was wondering this problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[#19962](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19962): The documentation has been updated. Basically, this is not a bug in Django, but rather a special settings in Chrome which allows user to continue its browser session even after closing and re-opening the browser.

See the [note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions) in the updated docs.

> Some browsers (Chrome, for example) provide settings that allow users to continue browsing sessions after closing and re-opening the browser. In some cases, this can interfere with the **`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE`** setting and prevent sessions from expiring on browser close. Please be aware of this while testing Django applications which have the **`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE`** setting enabled.

Comment: Is there a work around to make session expire using Django when browser is closed

Comment: @Aseem Have you got any solution

Comment: Try `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE =True` in settings.py . Then close your browser entirely (not just a tab) and reopen it.